# SpringDataGraph findByProperty not working with Neo4J

Tags: spring, persistence, neo4j, spring-data-graph

When I run the code below, a new User with the expected properties is created. (I confirm with Neoclipse after running the test). However, `findByPropertyValue` fails to retrieve the user. It just returns null. When I debug I find that `usrFromDb1` only seems to contain null-values, even those values that I later confirmed *were* infact saved in the databse!
Does anyone have an idea for a solution?

```
  @Test(enabled = true, groups = {"functest"})
    public void shouldGetUserDetails() throws Exception {
      User user = new User("admin", "secretpw").persist();

      User usrFromDb1 = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());
      assertNotNull(usr1); //succeeds

      User usrFromDb2 = userRepository.findByPropertyValue("username", "admin");
      assertNotNull(usr2); //fails
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an `@Indexed` property on your username attribute.

Could you please show your `User` class?

The user's fields are null in debug b/c in this mapping mode they are handled transparently by AspectJ, if you call `user.getUserName()` in the debugger this should yield the value.

Also the variable names in your asserts don't match those from your query-results
.e.g `usrFromDb2` vs. `usr2`

Comment: Thanks, it was @Indexed that was missing!